# Designing Feedback database table

Tags: sql, database-design

What attributes should be in the Feedback table?

First of all I do not require any login for feedback. So I'm putting the following column in my table:

For Example

1. Subject = that about what is the purpose of feedback.
2. message = description of subject.
3. contact Number
4. Email = to contact the user or replay the answer to subject
5. Name = for calling the user purpose
6. FeedBack_Date= TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
   Do I need any primary key in my table? And if so, why do I need the primary key? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary is used to identify a particular row in your table.

Say if you are getting multiple feed back from the same customer,you can't identify them from the fields that you mentioned. You can just list out it based on the name or email of the customer. If there is an ID (primary key) you can tell that this is the first feedback that we received from a particular customer or something like that. Again its better to add a 'feedback date' as a field in your table so that you can track the feedbacks.

Here is the sample schema.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Feedback
  ([ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, --Primary key of your table
   [Subject] VARCHAR(500),
   [Message] VARCHAR(MAX),-- limit the datatype as per your allowed characters
   [Name]  VARCHAR(150),
   [Contactnumber] VARCHAR(20),
   [Email] VARCHAR(150),
   [ReceivedDate] DATETIME Default(GETDATE()) --the date you received the feedback 
   )
```

Comment: ok so did you mean should i have to make an arbitrary id column with auto increment ???? and Thanks for feedback date variable I'll make it as a column of feedback table

Comment: ok I make an attribute Feedback_Date (TIMESTAMP on update). did the datatype I use is correct ?? ?

Comment: You can give datetime as data type and set default as getdate (). That will generate the feedback date for every entry in your feedback table..

Comment: ok get date will work automatically whenever a new feedback is generated ??? or i have to code it backend in php ?

Comment: Since we set getdate() as default to that column, it will generate automatically for every insert..

Comment: and did it get time also ?

Comment: ok i use to alter table and write the following sysntax but error comes up , alter table feedback add column Feedback_Date Datetime DEFAULT(GETDATE()) I'm creating db on sql on phpmyadmin

Comment: ok i did this by using datatype DATETIME and default use of current_TIMESTAMP and now() function of mysql

Answer (score 1):

*What attributes should be in the Feedback table?*

It depends on your business logic. In extreme case you can store everything in one field and you will still be able to read it. But I hope it's not what you want.

In your suggested column list I am missing some timestamp (to store at what time the message was sent) and any system information (IP, browser info, etc.)

*should I need any primary key in it if does than why so and why should i need the primary key*

Primary key uniquely identifies the individual row, so data manipulation and sorting becomes easier.

Comment: ok so what kind of timestamp variable should i have to make.. and in my situation do i need any primary key. Thank you

Comment: ok I Got this ALTER TABLE `feedback` CHANGE `Feedback_Date` `Feedback_Date` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I would strongly recommend a primary key. The easiest way to do a simple key is create the column this way

```
feedbackID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

In the above example the first 1 is the starting seed and the second 1 is the increment. You may want to give the user a case # (his feedbackID) and in that case maybe you want to start with a random number or 10,000. Instead of saying your case # is 1 you can assign it 10001 or I usually start 10123 so it doesn't appear its a new site, new app, etc. That is a personal preference and has not functionally required.

**NOTE:** Its important you add a date field so you know when the feedback came in.

Comment: 'feedbackID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL' <br> ok so It will automatically increment ??? like we don't have to use auto increment ??? and did I have to make this feedbackID as a Primary key ????